# What symbol is this that appears on the VS.NET IDE?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Everyonce in a while I click in something that makes this symbol appear. What is it and what does it serve for?

[alt text http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/7335/unknownlsk.jpg](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/7335/unknownlsk.jpg)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it's a bookmark - it serves to let you find a particular bit of code again later.

Edit: it is indeed - see: http://msmvps.com/blogs/vipul/archive/2006/01/20/Visual-Studio-Bookmarks.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's a bookmark, and it's very useful when you want to move around your code. To set a new bookmark, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> +<kbd>k</kbd>.

To move between bookmarks use the following:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> to move to the next bookmark.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>  to move to the previous bookmark.

To remove a bookmark, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> again on the same line.